# How to compute a value using edit text but not using button [android]

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have 3 edit box and one button but below the code I use button to compute
I tired using textwatcher but their is no adjustment at all
My question is there a way to automatically compute a value using edit text only without a button.

```
**[update code]**

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Cal extends Activity implements TextWatcher{

    EditText amount1, amount2,tt;

    Button cal;
    double x=0;
    double y=0;
    double t=0.45;
    double m=0.025;
    double v=1.575;
    double w=0;
    double a=0;
    double b=0;
    double c=0;
    double d=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calculate);

        amount1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edT);
        amount1.addTextChangedListener(this);
        amount2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt2);
        amount2.addTextChangedListener(this);
        tt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtotal);
        tt.addTextChangedListener(this);


    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(amount1.getText().toString() != null && amount2.getText().toString() != null)
        {
           x=Double.parseDouble(amount1.getText().toString());
            y=Double.parseDouble(amount2.getText().toString());
            a = x * t ;
            b = y * m;
            c = b * v;
            d = a / c;
            //e = d * 100;
            tt.setText(""+ d);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Search for edit text onTextChangedListener()

Comment: onTextChangedListener() or addTextChangedListener?

Comment: why u have casted your edtotal (it seems EditText) to TextView while creating object tt

Comment: my bad. i already change it. but still nothing happen. help me please

Comment: hi code143 have you find solution

Comment: if u got your solution, you can upvote the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your updated & working code just paste it

```
 public class Cal extends Activity implements TextWatcher {

        EditText amount1, amount2, tt;

    Button cal;
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
    double t = 0.45;
    double m = 0.025;
    double v = 1.575;
    double w = 0;
    double a = 0;
    double b = 0;
    double c = 0;
    double d = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calculate);

        amount1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edT);
        amount1.addTextChangedListener(this);
        amount2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt2);
        amount2.addTextChangedListener(this);
        tt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtotal);

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (amount1.getText().toString().length() > 0
                && amount2.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
            x = Double.parseDouble(amount1.getText().toString());
            y = Double.parseDouble(amount2.getText().toString());
            a = x * t;
            b = y * m;
            c = b * v;
            d = a / c;
            // e = d * 100;
            tt.setText("" + d);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it said: NumberFormatException: Invalid double:""

Comment: have u put if condition in onTextChanged as code i posted

Comment: yes i did. please check the code i posted above. i will update it

Comment: NumberFormatException is due to forced conversion of empty String in Double.
Instead of' !=null' , put '...tostring.length>0'